# WPF triggers or ViewModel INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: wpf, poco, datatrigger

I am making a WPF Datagrid with lots of related columns. When you change X, Y should be X + Z. Etc. My first idea was to do this in the ViewModel properties with INotifyPropertyChanged. But I see that this also can be done with WPF triggers.

**IMHO**

If I do it with ViewModel/INotifyPropertyChanged there will be a problem with the first time initializing, where you do not want these rules to execute. I guess I could come around this by setting the private variables in a constructor.
The WPF trigger solution seems to be more complex and much more difficult to test.

**Question**

Are there any advantages letting WPF triggers do the job?

Comment: Please add more concrete issues to avoid having this question treated as an opinion survey.  There are positives and negatives to either approach and your own criteria should be given in the body of the question.

Comment: Tried that, but isn't easy. This is not math and I'm new to WPF :)

Comment: I think you should read one more time about Triggers and Notifing Properties. and focus on where shoud use witch one.

Comment: Seriously Jodha!? How do you know when you have done enough reading before asking on SO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've asked a bit of a subjective question here without much possibility of a definitive answer. However, I'm going to give it a try.

In my opinion, I would always manipulate data in the view model, for two main reasons:

1. Data manipulation = business rules and that belongs in the view model and not the view
2. You have access to every property of the data item(s) and every method in .NET in the view model, but access to very little in a `Trigger`.

I hope that helps in some small way.